# How to convert int[] to ByteBuffer in Java?

Tags: java, c++, java-native-interface

as the title already says, I need to convert an int[] to a ByteBuffer in Java. Is there a recommended way to do this ?

I want to pass the ByteBuffer over JNI to C++. What do I have to look out for regarding any specific endian conversions in this case ?

Edit: Sorry, I mistakenly wrote ByteArray but meant the type ByteBuffer.

Edit: Sample code:

I stripped out the unnecessary parts. I call a Java function over JNI from c++ to load a resource and pass it back to c++ as bytebuffer. It works with various other resources. Now I have an "int []" and would like to know if there is an elegant way to convert it to a bytebuffer or if I have to go the oldfashioned way and fill it in a for loop.

```
ByteBuffer  resource= null;
resource = ByteBuffer.allocateDirect((x*y+2)*4).order(ByteOrder.nativeOrder());
.
.
ByteBuffer GetResourcePNG(String text)
{
    .
    .
    int []  pix;
    map.getPixels(pix,0,x,0,0,x,y);

    return resource;
}
```

Comment: Is that right? I mean, a ByteBuffer is an abstract class. What's the exact type that you need? please provide some sample code.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You have to use [`ByteBuffer.allocateDirect`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/nio/ByteBuffer.html#allocateDirect(int)) if you want to be able to use [JNI's `GetDirectBufferAddress`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/guide/jni/jni-14.html#GetDirectBufferAddress).

Use [`ByteBuffer.order(ByteOrder.nativeOrder())`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/nio/ByteBuffer.html#order(java.nio.ByteOrder)) to adjust the `ByteBuffer` instance's endianness to match the current platform.

After the `ByteBuffer`'s endianness is properly configured, use [`ByteBuffer.asIntBuffer()`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/nio/ByteBuffer.html#asIntBuffer()) to get a view of it as a `java.nio.IntBuffer` and fill it with your data.

**Full Example**:

```
import java.nio.ByteBuffer; import java.nio.ByteOrder; import java.nio.IntBuffer;

public class Test {
    static final int bytes_per_datum = 4;

    public static void main(String args[]) {
        main2("Native Endian", ByteOrder.nativeOrder());
        main2("Big Endian", ByteOrder.BIG_ENDIAN);
        main2("Little Endian", ByteOrder.LITTLE_ENDIAN);
    }

    static void main2(String comment, ByteOrder endian) {
        int[] data = { 1, 0xF, 0xFF, 0xFFF, 0xFFFF, 0xFFFFF, 0xFFFFFF, 0xFFFFFFF, 0xFFFFFFFF };
        ByteBuffer bb = ByteBuffer.allocateDirect(data.length * bytes_per_datum);
        bb.order(endian); // endian must be set before putting ints into the buffer
        put_ints(bb, data);

        System.out.println(comment + ": ");
        print(bb);
    }

    static void put_ints(ByteBuffer bb, int[] data) {
        IntBuffer b = bb.asIntBuffer(); // created IntBuffer starts only from the ByteBuffer's relative position
                                        // if you plan to reuse this IntBuffer, be mindful of its position
        b.put(data); // position of this IntBuffer changes by +data.length;
    } // this IntBuffer goes out of scope

    static void print(ByteBuffer bb) { // prints from start to limit
        ByteBuffer bb_2 = bb.duplicate(); // shares backing content, but has its own capacity/limit/position/mark (equivalent to original buffer at initialization)
        bb_2.rewind();
        for (int x = 0, xx = bb_2.limit(); x < xx; ++x) {
            System.out.print((bb_2.get() & 0xFF) + " "); // 0xFF for display, since java bytes are signed
            if ((x + 1) % bytes_per_datum == 0) {
                System.out.print(System.lineSeparator());
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Hi, the last line gives an error "asIntBuffer can not be resolved or is not a field".

Comment: Sorry, my mistake. I am at it for 16hours straight and definitely need a break. Thanks alot for your help though.

Comment: still I see you edited your question. I don't know exactly what you're at but if you need to load PNGs from C++, just use the wonderful std_image lib: http://nothings.org/stb_image.c

Comment: Someone asked for sample code before I saw your reply so I added it. I am coding on an Android Device and read the images from the resources. I also try to keep all interaction with the system/files/etc. on the java side because on c++ its a real pain to debug. But thanks for the lib.

Answer (score 2):

you could convert to matrix in this way:

```
public static final byte[] intToByteArray(int value) {
    return new byte[] {
            (byte)(value >>> 24),
            (byte)(value >>> 16),
            (byte)(value >>> 8),
            (byte)value};
}

int[] arrayOfInt = {1,2,3,4,5,6};
byte[][] matrix = new byte[arrayOfInt.length][size];
for(int i=0;i<arrayOfInt.length;i++)
   byte[i] = intToByteArray(arrayOfInt[i]);
```

Comment: I mistakenly wrote ByteArray but meant the type ByteBuffer. But I do can actually use what you wrote at another part of my code, so thank you very much. :-)

Answer (score 0):

Any reason for not passing the `int[]` array directly to the C++ or C code using JNI as [per the example mentioned here](http://java.sun.com/developer/onlineTraining/Programming/JDCBook/jnistring.html#array)?

Comment: Hi, thank you for your reply. The reason that I would not like to change it is that I have quite a few interactions with JNI and I always pass a ByteBuffer for data transfer and would like to keep it like that.